# Determinant of Riemannian metric $g_{ij}$

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, finsler-geometry

I am unclear about the calculation of $det(g_{ij})$ are there any tips or starting steps to reach this result?

I tried to rewrite $g_{ij}$ and I got:

$g_{ij}=a_{ij}(\rho+s(\rho_{0}s+\frac{3}{4}\rho_{1}))$,
where $\rho,\rho_{0}$ and $\rho_{1}$ are the same as bellow.

I saw in a propozition that $det(g_{ij})$ can be calculated as:
$det(g_{ij})=(1+\delta c^2) det (h_{ij})$, where $(h_{ij})$ is a symmetric matrix, and $c=\sqrt(h^{ij}c_i c_j)$.
But I don't understand how it's supposed to be used.
If someone has any advices, or can explain the first steps I need to make so I'll understand what I need to do, I will be grateful!
I also searched in articles but unfortunately I didn't crossed with anything helpful.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. To begin with, what is $g_{ij}$? This looks like a Riemannian metric, not a general Finsler metric. The rest is unclear as well.

Comment: Presumably, you know what the determinant of a matrix is and what its properties are? Or are you asking how to get the tensor $g_{ij}\,dx^idx^j$ from a Finsler metric?

Comment: Hi, I'm asking how do I calculate det(g_ij) with g_ij given above in the image.